# Dynamic data in rails partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I've just started to use Partials in my rails application, at the moment i have the following code in my application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'categories/categorieslist' %>
```

This links to _categorieslist.html.erb in my views/categories/ folder

At the moment this partial contains hard coded hyperlinks

```
<ul class="unstyled">
    <li style="padding-bottom:5px"><a href="#">Item A&raquo;</a></li>
    <li style="padding-bottom:5px"><a href="#">Item B&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

My aim is to have these categories coming from the database, e.g

```
<ul class="unstyled">
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <li style="padding-bottom:5px"><a href="#"><%= category.name %> &raquo;    </a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

I have tried adding a categorieslist method in the categories controller e.g

```
def categorieslist
 @categories = Category.all
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @categories }
   end
  end
```

but this is not being called by the partial (and i don't feel this is even the correct way to do it), and is showing the error

```
NoMethodError in Store#index
```

on the line <% @categories.each do |category| %>

My question is how do i pass into the partial in the application.html.erb file, the categories object that usually would come from a controller method in the categories controller?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send `locales` with your partial call in your view and pass variables to that partial.

For example (this is a partial shortcut):

Your view from which you call the partial

```
<%= render 'categories/categorieslist', :all_categories => @categories %>
```

Your partial categories/_categorieslist.html.erb (note there is no @ with the variable)

```
<ul class="unstyled">
  <% all_categories.each do |category| %>
    <li style="padding-bottom:5px"><a href="#"><%= category.name %> &raquo;    </a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

For further information (and the long version), see [3.4.4 Passing Local Variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) in the Rails Guides.

Comment: Thanks, one thing i am not too sure about is how to arrange the code so that the @ categories collection passed into this partial is populated by a call to @ categories = Category.all, where should this activerecord query be arranged in the code, if the partial is in the layout file application.html.erb?

Comment: If it is in application.html.erb, it should go into your ApplicationController. Here you can either make a before_filter and a method like def `get_cats @categories = Category.all end` or you can directly call the method (it returns the last value in the method) with `<%= render 'categories/categorieslist', :all_categories => get_cats %>`

Comment: Thats great, i wasn't sure if it was possible to include such things in the ApplicationController and hadnt found any clear examples, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a collection for this:

```
<%= render 'categories/categorieslist', :collection => @categories, :as => :category %>
```

This renders a collection of items. In this case, all the categories. You can also pass it a custom name with the :as => .

Then in your partial you only include the stuff you want the items in the collection to render:

```
<li style="padding-bottom:5px"><a href="#"><%= category.name %> &raquo; </a></li>
```

The -ul- isn't included as it would be rendered multiple times. You'll need to wrap it around your render tag.

The result is the same as the suggestion @timbrandes outlined, (check out docs he linked to).

I've heard :collection gives you performance improvements. 
http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/38-use-render-collection-rails-3-when-possible

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right way to do it, and your question is rather confusing.

I'd say that you still have to read a rails book. You seem to be still a bit too fresh

Anyway, controller methods usually represent http requests. And they are invoked accordingly to what is defined in the config/routes file. Views (*.erb) do not usually invoke controller methods. If they do so, they do it through an ajax request.

Data is passed from actions to the views through controllers instance variables.

If you want to invoke any methods within the views, they should be defined in helpers. Still, the only data they will manipulate is the one passed from controllers as instance variables.